# SDL2 linker problems, MinGW translates wrong path from cmake

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I've been trying to add SDL2 library to a program, but I keep getting this error:

> 'SDL.h' file not found

Here's the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/SDL2/i686-w64- 
mingw32/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

message(STATUS IncludeDir=${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) 
message(STATUS IncludeLib=${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

The cmake output after regen is:

> -- IncludeDir=/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2

> -- IncludeLib=-L/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows

> -- Configuring done

> -- Generating done

> -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO3fG.png) of the project's structure, and a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO4vh.png) of the include directory, the SDL2 directory entirely is *included* in the project files.

The include folder has all the header files and contain SDL.h which makes this odd because the compiler should be able to find it.

I'm using the CLion IDE and MinGW compiler.
This project is a test project to add SDL2 and make it work, thus I only have the main class and it contains this:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main() {

return 0;
}
```

Edit: I changed the include to give the full path to SDL.h so main is:

```
#include "SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL.h"

int main() {

return 0;
}
```

So the file is found but when I run it the following error appears:

> [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj

> [2/2] Linking CXX executable test.exe

> FAILED: test.exe

> cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -g

> CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -o test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a
> -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -L/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows  -lmingw32  -lSDL2main  -lSDL2  -mwindows  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Second Edit:

After changing CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE, the build log again is:

> "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\Windows 10\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug" --target test

> [1/2] "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"  -I/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -c "C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/main.cpp"

> [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -g  CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -o test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -L/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

> FAILED: test.exe

> cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -g  CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -o test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -L/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main

> D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Changing back to include "SDL.h" only and running on the same cmake config gives this:

> "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build
> "C:\Users\Windows 10\CLionProjects\test\cmake-build-debug" --target test

> [1/2] "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"  -I/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -c "C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/main.cpp"

> FAILED: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj

> "D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"  -I/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj -c "C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/main.cpp"

> C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory

> 1 | #include "SDL.h"
> |          ^~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Like what @Someprogrammerdude said the include directory is being set as /opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 instead of the actual path C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2

Comment: In the linked image, the most important part (the structure of the `include` directory and its sub-directories) is not shown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added it now, it just contains a folder that contains all the header files for SDL

Comment: You use the wrong command, instead of [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) you should be using [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changed it, still doesn't find SDL.h

Comment: While it shouldn't matter, does changing `#include "SDL.h"` to `#include <SDL.h>` change anything?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No it didn't change anything.

Comment: And please open up your `CMakeCache.txt` file (can be accessed from the CMake tab in CLion) and change the `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable from `FALSE` to `TRUE`. Reload the project and build. You should now get all the commands including all flags and options. Look to make sure that they are okay, and that the correct include path is passed. Please copy-paste the commands that runs (as text) into your question.

Comment: I'm also a little worried that the include directory is set as `/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2` instead of the actual path `C:/Users/Windows 10/CLionProjects/test/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2`. There seems to be some kind of MinGW translation of the paths that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edited but I wasn't exactly sure on where to look for all the flags as the build log changed a bit but the cmake one didn't at all

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're correct, the include directory path set is being "I/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2" instead of the absolute path but the thing is I need to move the project from machine to machine so I need to use the relative path anyways

Comment: If the linker says "cannot find -lSDL2" then it cannot find -lSDL2. The only place where it can locate third party libraries is `/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib` because that's what you pass to it. Check yourself: do you have any directory named `/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib` on your machine? are there any files directly in it (not any subdirectory) that are named `SDL2.*` or `libSDL2.*` with some kind of library suffix (lib, a, so)?

Comment: `the include directory path set is being "I/opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2"` No, not really. The letter `I` is not a part of the path. "I need to use the relative path anyways" It is an absolute path. You cannot use relative paths with Cmake (easily, or at all).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Include paths obviously work because the project gets to the linker stage and fails there. Fiddling with them can only make it fail earlier.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The question has been edited and updated with a more complete path to the header file. It was originally asking about a failure about finding the `SDL.h` header file.

Comment: If you have `bash` included with mingw or clion or cmake or whatever, run it, and type the command `cygpath -w /opt/local/i686-w64-mingw32`. This will print the Windows equivalent of that path. Check that it exists and has required files. Note if you have several instances of `bash` that come with different tools, each may translate the path differently. To translate back, use `cygpath 'D:\Clion\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw'` (note single quotes).